# Multiple Titles in LaTeX

Tags: titles

Maybe this is a really basic question but i can't seem to find an appropriate answer. For my master's degree thesis i need to have several titles in the cover (university name, my title, the subject of the work, etc.). Any elegant way to implement this?

(My university unfortunately does not provide any LaTeX template. By the way, suggestions have been awesome so far!)

I needed a cover similar to this:

[image]

Comment: May be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11232+title+page

Comment: probably want to use `\begin{titlepage}...` environment to make a custom title page.

Comment: Some universities have existing LaTeX templates for theses. If there is such a template, it would have the necessary title page, and laid out to university standards. That might provide a good starting point.

Comment: Can you point to a typical cover similar to the one you need?

Comment: Just an academia related remark: make sure you may use the logo of the university. Usually they are only allowed on official documents. A thesis, however handed in to that institution, is no such document.

Comment: Martin, thank you so much for your remark but indeed we are allowed (and actually must) use the logo. thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One could control the entries using in `\maketitle` (such as `\title`, `\author` and/or `\date`). However, for large documents its simplest to use the `titlepage` environment and enter the content as is required by the university's specification. Here's a rough template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
{\LARGE\bfseries My thesis title}

\vspace{1cm}

{\Large Some subtitle for my thesis}

\vspace{2cm}

{\large An Author}

\vspace{2cm}

{\bfseries Submitted in fulfillment of the degree \ldots}

\vfill

{\itshape University of Randomville}
\end{titlepage}

% Other content goes here...

\end{document}
```

With exact specifications one can provide a more accurate template.